# React redux - parent state changing, but child components not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am just trying to learn to use redux, and I have a very simple counter list component which has a list of child counter components.

I have an onIncrement action on the counter, which I want to increment the count when clicked.

When I click the increment it updates the parent state, however the child counter does not update.  If I browse away and then back to the list, it does render correctly, which seems to me to mean that the state has updated.

Here is my code:

**Counter Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { incrementCounter } from '../../actions/counterActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="m-2">
            <b>{this.props.counter.count}</b>
            <button className="btn btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2" onClick={() => { this.onIncrement(this.props.counter) }}>Increment</button>
        </div>;
    }

    onIncrement(counter) {
        this.props.incrementCounter(counter);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
})

Counter.propTypes = {
    incrementCounter: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { incrementCounter })(Counter);
```

**Counter List component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import { CounterContext } from "../../contexts/context.js";
import Counter from "./Counter";
import { NewItem } from "./NewItem";
import ItemContainer from "../layout/ItemContainer";

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCounters } from '../../actions/counterActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class CounterList extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.counters.length == 0) {
            this.props.getCounters();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const counterItems = this.props.counters.map(counter => <Counter key={counter.id} counter={counter} />);
        return <div>{ counterItems }</div>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    counters: state.counters.items
})

CounterList.propTypes = {
    getCounters: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    counters: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCounters })(CounterList);
```

**Counter Actions**

```
import { GET_COUNTERS, INCREMENT_COUNTERS } from '../actions/types';

export const getCounters = () => dispatch => {
    const counters = [{ id: 1, count: 4 }, { id: 2, count: 3 }, { id: 3, count: 0 }];
    // this could be API call to get initial counters
    console.log('In GetCounters', GET_COUNTERS);

    return dispatch({
        type: GET_COUNTERS,
        payload: counters
    })
}

export const incrementCounter = (counter) => dispatch => {
    // this could be API call to get initial counters
    counter.count++;

    return dispatch({
        type: INCREMENT_COUNTERS,
        payload: counter
    })
}
```

**Counter reducers**

```
import { GET_COUNTERS, INCREMENT_COUNTERS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: []
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    console.log(action.type);
    switch (action.type){
        case GET_COUNTERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        case INCREMENT_COUNTERS:
            var counter = action.payload;

            const counters = [...state.items];
            const index = counters.findIndex(x => x.id == counter.id);
            counters[index] = counter;

            return {
                ...state,
                items: counters
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the problem could be that you are assigning the same old counter object with the updated value of count to your counters[index] and hence the Counter component doesn't see a change. This could be because shouldComponentUpdate does a shallow check and the object reference to the counter prop remains the same and your component doesn't re-render.

You should be using deep cloning if you are using multi-dimensional arrays or nested objects in your state.

Use libraries like Immutable.js is recommended to make sure your reducers remain pure.

```js
case INCREMENT_COUNTERS:
  var counter = action.payload;

  const counters = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.items)); //this creates a deep copy
  const index = counters.findIndex(x => x.id == counter.id);
  counters[index].count = counter.count;

  return {
    ...state,
    items: counters
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this turned out to be the issue, setting the counters to a deep copy as well as setting the count specifically has made the counter work.  Thanks so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're not mapping the state to props, for example:

```
function mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { count: state.count }; 
}
```

This will map the state in your redux that reflects the change of the counter to the props of your component where you wanna display the current count. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, where do I need to add this?  I've tried in the counter component and this hasn't worked

Comment: in the Counter Component mapStateToProps function.

Comment: The state doesn't have a count property on it, just a list of counters...  I tried the following, which does map it to the correct counter, but this still doesn't update... const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    counter: state.counters.items.find(counter => counter.id == ownProps.id)
});

Answer (score 1):

You could try put `componentWillReceiveProps` inside your `Counter` component and check if you are getting the new `counter` props every time you click the button.

Comment: Ok, so tried this with just a console.log("componentWillReceiveProps", nextProps); and it's not hitting this at all

Comment: put an extra prop like ```<Counter key={counter.id} counter={counter} aa={counter.count} />``` and see. I think it is because your store.items is a list of mutable objects, and the ```counter++``` in  your INCREMENT_COUNTERS still modify the same object instead of returning a new one, that's why react update didn't pick it up.